# How many edges does a full binary tree with 1000 internal vertices have?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Following my textbooks definition of a full binary tree, which is: If T is a full binary tree with i internal vertices, then T's total vertices = 2i + 1. So with 1000 internal vertices, there would be 2001 total vertices.

I then used this formula to calculate the number of edges. E = (total vertices)-1. The answer would then be 2000 edges, Am I right?

Comment: You ought to mention the *other* formula that you used (relating number of edges to number of vertices in a tree).

Comment: ok just edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
$$
|E| = |V| - 1 = \left( 2|V_{int}| + 1 \right) - 1 = 2 |V_{int}|,
$$
and
$$
2 \cdot 1000 = 2000.
$$

However, it's easy to see the answer directly.  In a *full, binary* tree, each *internal* vertex has exactly two edges emanating from it.  End of story.